# Firebase deploy - firebase.json not working for ignore node_modules and src files

Tags: firebase, deployment, node-modules, firebase-hosting

After deploying, or even after "firebase serve", node_modules and src files should be hidden in the static folder when inspect on Google Chrome, but not happens.

This is my firebase.json for a react project.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/src/**",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Folders and files structure:

```
27/07/2022  10:34    <DIR>          .
27/07/2022  10:34    <DIR>          ..
01/07/2022  21:41    <DIR>          .firebase
30/06/2022  18:31                56 .firebaserc
01/07/2022  22:33               343 .gitignore
27/07/2022  09:56    <DIR>          build
27/07/2022  10:35               143 firebase.json
27/07/2022  09:32    <DIR>          node_modules
27/07/2022  09:31           600.237 package-lock.json
27/07/2022  09:27               862 package.json
30/06/2022  19:02    <DIR>          public
26/10/1985  05:15             2.891 README.md
27/07/2022  09:18    <DIR>          src
```

After cmd "C:\Documents\REACT\myapp>firebase serve, the result in http://localhost:5000/ (image below) shows that node_modules is not hidden. I would like /node_modules/ as well as other files in /src/ to be hidden.

[image about http://localhost:5000/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rFYC.png)

Comment: I think it would help to explain in more detail what exactly you are doing and how the result is different than what you expect.  We should be able to duplicate your observations using the instructions you provide in the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for following the issue.. After cmd "C:\Documents\REACT\myapp>firebase serve, the result in http://localhost:5000/ (image was added in addition to the initial question) shows that node_modules is not hidden. I would like /node_modules/ as well as other files in /src/ to be hidden.